# std::list.begin() giving null pointer

Tags: c++

I have a structure defined that contains a std::list. In my code, I try to iterate through this list, but I get some odd results.

```
struct my_struct_t {
    std::list<int> my_list;
    //More fields
};
```

This is my structure as defined in my header file.

And some sample code in a file that includes this header would be:

```
    std::list<int>::iterator my_iterator;

    struct my_struct_t* test_struct = (struct my_struct_t*) malloc(sizeof(struct my_struct_t));
    my_iterator = test_struct->my_list.begin();
    printf("Beginning of list address: %p\n", my_iterator);

    my_iterator = test_struct->my_list.end();
    printf("End of the list address: %p\n", my_iterator);
    printf("Address of the list: %p\n", &(test_struct->my_list));
```

This code compiles and runs fine, but the output would be something like:

```
Beginning of list address: (nil)
End of the list address: 0x86f010
Address of the list: 0x86f010
```

The last two lines make perfect sense to me, since the list should be empty. But how/why am I getting a null pointer for the beginning? How can I fix this?

Comment: Step 1: Read a good C++ primer, pick one among [those](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Step 2: realize that despite the many similarities, C++ and C are very different languages and are only really alike in their flaws.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't `malloc` a list and then use it without initialization. This is an invalid operation.

It has not been initialized with a proper `new` call. That this works at all without blowing a segfault is amazing.

You will need to create your `my_struct_t` object using a C++ style initialization or it won't work.

Have you tried something more C++ like:

```
struct my_struct_t* test_struct = new my_struct_t;
```

Later on instead of a `free` call you would `delete` of course.

Comment: You don't need a new call.. but at least a call to the constructor

Comment: Calling a constructor on a `malloc`'d object seems like a dangerous road to go down. If the `list` has a destructor you'd have to call that manually before issuing a `free`.

Comment: Yes. I meant : you could create your sctruct on the stack... or call a new for the struct, not the list

Comment: Nothing there is invalid. The code is just not doing what he expects. He could still use placement new to correctly initialize the object and code like this has valid use-cases.

Comment: I think that approach would get [the book](http://www.aristeia.com/books.html) thrown at you. Considering how the `new` call is significantly easier to perform, there's really no reason to do a `malloc` here.

Comment: @tadman Sure, this is not really what he wants to do. But your answer is giving the impression of something not being permissible, which is false.

Comment: I've clarified my answer slightly to address this.

Answer (score 1):

`malloc` will only allocate the necessary memory for an object, but will not initialize that object. Initialization of an object in C++ is performed by its constructor. C++ provides the operator `new` to allocate memory and initialize an object at the same time. So what you should have done is:

```
my_struct_t* x = new my_struct_t();
```

If you really intended to use `malloc` here, you can still properly initialize an object on in correctly aligned raw-memory by using `placement new`. Keep in mind that you will then have to call the destructor explicitly and deallocate the memory explicitly as well. But I seriously doubt this was your intention.